# How do you call the vice-principals?

Tags: word-request

There are various types of vice-principal:

- The person who oversees the school inventory (things they have, things they need, what to buy, when to buy, etc.)
- The person who oversees curriculum (setting curriculum for next academic year, evaluating the current curriculum, etc.)
- The person who oversees the student activity (which student goes to what competition, which student earn/deserve scholarship, school clubs, etc.)
- The person who oversees communication with the public and other schools

How do you call these vice-principals in English: inventory vice-principal, curriculum vice-principal? Is that how they are called, or is there a special term for them?

Comment: In academia, it's often *Vice Principal of _____*.

Comment: For us in the US, we just called them all Vice Principals and what they oversaw was not part of their title, but their job responsibility. Meanwhile, if you do want to put it into the title, I would agree with and had upvoted J.R.'s comment. However, a last comment, seeing that you hyphenated the term, I would have to let you know that these terms are [culture- and American-English-/British-English-specific](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vice-principal) so you may want to follow what's done in your country or in the country you want to emulate.

Comment: Might wanna ask at academie SE http://academia.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because an answer would only be valid for one school system - it's likely to not even be true over any large country that has multiple school systems. It's a question about either school education or academia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In American public schools, responsibilities are divided in various ways, and the terminology used depends on the school. However, as mentioned in the comments, most US schools will just have a job title of "Principal" or "Vice Principal" and not describe what that person's specific duties are.

At my public high school in the northeast US, we did not have any vice principals. Instead, we had 5 principals. One oversaw the entire building, and he was called the "head principal." The others were each assigned to a class year: freshman, sophomores, juniors, or seniors, and were called by their class year name. They each did many of those things for their specific students. However, the school had other people that did some of the other tasks. There was a "Head of facilities" that oversaw supplies, cooking, cleaning, and groundskeeping. Each academic department had a "Chair of ____ (Mathematics, Biology, Arts, etc.)" who oversaw curriculum evaluation but was also a teacher.

In some private schools in the US and in some English Speaking schools elsewhere, the title "Dean" is used. This is also true at most colleges and universities. So A college might have a "Dean of Faculty" or a "Dean of Academics" or a "Dean of Students" etc. Private high schools in the US also sometimes use this term.